# Cast Regular Pointer to FLASH Pointer in IAR

Tags: c, embedded, iar

IAR defines the __flash keyword to specify that a pointer is pointing to FLASH space when used like

```
uint8_t __flash *dataPtr;
```

I'm trying to take an address passed into a function via a regular pointer, and use the FLASH pointer to point at that address in FLASH. I'm restricted for portability reasons (across other architectures) to using the regular pointer to pass in, so I can't just change my function defintion. Can't seem to find any way to "cast" away the __flash modifier. I put in a ticket to IAR but am really trying to wrap this up this weekend.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: IAR produce tools for many architectures; the __flash keyword is architecture specific - you need to be specific about the architecture you are targetting.

Comment: You might do better to pass addresses as integers then cast to a pointer as necesary.

Comment: What's the effect of `const uint8_t __flash *dataPtr = (const uint8_t __flash *)givenPtr;`? Any error message? Some more details would be great